# A LaTeX 3 macro to typeset chemical compounds?

Tags: macros, latex3, expl3

Out of curiosity, I wonder how would a macro coded in [`expl3`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3) that does the basics of [`mhchem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) (as in section **basics** in the [`mhchem` manual](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf)) looks like?

[image: mhchem]

I have found examples in TeX and LuaTeX in http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Programming_in_LuaTeX but their input style is too close to math (in my view, not as convenient as`mhchem`).

So, gurus, please showcase the power of `expl3`.

Comment: I wrote the wiki page that you cite. I will start by noting that i know nothin about typesetring chemical formulas but what is so so ugly about the input syntax. I glanced at mhchem syntax and the main difference appears to how underscores are handled. If you have a formal grammer of how mhchem parses its input it should be straigjtforward to write the parse in lpeg.

Comment: mhchem.sty is 1300 lines long. What exactly are you asking to be reimplemented?

Comment: And what would a reimplementation get us? P.S. @Aditya: "without exploding your head" is a great phrase `:)` I haven't used LPEG but that seems like a good approach.

Comment: @Aditya: the syntax is too close to math, isn't it? @Will: I don't know if implementing the basics of mhchem is a reimplementation of mhchem. It is 1300 lines and not easy to read. I was curious about whether using `expl3` will make the code easier to read just like what LPEG from Lua does.

Comment: I like the question. I don’t know `expl3` *at all* but if it can simplify parsing TeX, then a simple grammar such as the above might be well suited to showcase it. However, @Leo, providing a simple formal grammar might help make the question clearer and encourage answers.

Comment: @Konrad: I have no idea about the formal grammar. I don't use chemistry much. The compounds I use are GaAs, AlAs or InGaAs and they are fine just input as-is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't have a clue if this is sufficient to fully implement what `\ce` is capable of, but here's a quick example of how I'd go about this. Note that there are no state machines or active characters, just judicious use of search'n'replace. The TeX equivalent, I suppose, of a regexp solution. Who knows if it's efficient, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse,
  fixltx2e, % for \textsubscript
  amstext   % for \text
}

\newcommand\textsubsuperscript[2]{$_{\text{#1}}^{\text{#2}}$}
\newcommand\textsupersubscript[2]{$_{\text{#2}}^{\text{#1}}$}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% \catcode 12 strings of otherwise special chars:
\tl_set:Nx \c_underscore_char { \cs_to_str:N \_ }
\tl_set:Nx \c_caret_char      { \cs_to_str:N \^ }
\tl_set:Nx \c_bgroup_char     { \cs_to_str:N \{ }
\tl_set:Nx \c_egroup_char     { \cs_to_str:N \} }

\DeclareDocumentCommand \ce {m} {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_ce_tl { \tl_to_str:n {#1} }

  \tl_replace_all_in:Nnn \l_ce_tl {1} {\ce_sub:w{1}}
  \tl_replace_all_in:Nnn \l_ce_tl {2} {\ce_sub:w{2}}
  \tl_replace_all_in:Nnn \l_ce_tl {3} {\ce_sub:w{3}}
  \tl_replace_all_in:Nnn \l_ce_tl {4} {\ce_sub:w{4}}
  \tl_replace_all_in:Nnn \l_ce_tl {5} {\ce_sub:w{5}}
  \tl_replace_all_in:Nnn \l_ce_tl {6} {\ce_sub:w{6}}
  \tl_replace_all_in:Nnn \l_ce_tl {7} {\ce_sub:w{7}}
  \tl_replace_all_in:Nnn \l_ce_tl {8} {\ce_sub:w{8}}
  \tl_replace_all_in:Nnn \l_ce_tl {9} {\ce_sub:w{9}}
  \tl_replace_all_in:Nnn \l_ce_tl {0} {\ce_sub:w{0}}

  \tl_replace_all_in:Non \l_ce_tl \c_caret_char {\ce_super:w}
  \tl_replace_all_in:Non \l_ce_tl \c_underscore_char {\ce_sub:w}

  \tl_replace_all_in:Nnn \l_ce_tl {+} {\ce_super:w{+}}
  \tl_replace_all_in:Nnn \l_ce_tl {-} {\ce_super:w{$-$}}

  % fix syntax like "^2":
  \tl_replace_all_in:Nnn \l_ce_tl {\ce_super:w \ce_sub:w} {\ce_super:w}

  % finally, fix up braces that were detokenized:
  \tl_rescan:nV {\ExplSyntaxOn} \l_ce_tl
}

\cs_set:Npn \ce_super:w #1 {
  \peek_meaning_remove_ignore_spaces:NTF \ce_sub:w
  {\textsupersubscript{\ce_disable_subsuper: #1}}
  {\textsuperscript{\ce_disable_subsuper: #1}}
}

\cs_set:Npn \ce_sub:w #1 {
  \peek_meaning_remove_ignore_spaces:NTF \ce_super:w
  {\textsubsuperscript{\ce_disable_subsuper: #1}}
  {\textsubscript{\ce_disable_subsuper: #1}}
}

\cs_set:Nn \ce_disable_subsuper: {
  \cs_set_eq:NN \ce_super:w \use:n
  \cs_set_eq:NN \ce_sub:w \use:n
}

% Need these variants:
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all_in:Nnn {Non}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_rescan:nn {nV}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ce{Y^{99}+}\par
\ce{Y^{99+}}\par
\ce{H20}\par
\ce{Sb2O3}\par
\ce{H+}\par
\ce{CrO4^2-}\par
\ce{AgCl2-}\par
\ce{[AgCl2]-}\par
\ce{H2_{(aq)}}\par
\ce{NO3-}\par
\ce{(NH4)2S}\par
\end{document}
```

The premise of `\ce` is that the argument is turned into a string before replacing the various characters with macros to expand to the desired output. First the numbers are replaced by themselves inside a conditional subscript, then `^` and `_` are replaced macros to perform "conditional superscripts and subscripts" (resp.), and finally `+` and `-` are replaced by themselves superscripted.

In case of syntax like `^2`, which would be replaced by `[superscript]`+`[subscript 2]`, we replace the combination of `[superscript]`+`[subscript]` with the conditional superscript alone.

Finally, the string is the "retokenised" using the expl3 wrapper around `\scantokens` to perform all of the typesetting.

The "conditional subscripts" and "conditional superscripts" that I refer to above are simply text sub-/super-scripts that deactivates themselves for nested material. E.g., `[subscript [subscript x]]` is interpreted as `[subscript x]`. This allows things like `+` inside a superscript not superscripting itself again.

Comment: If you read through `mhchem` then I don't think efficiency comes into it. The approach above would leave a few questions, for example how to deal with single bonds (`\ce{C-H}`) and also escape to math mode (`\ce{$i\text{-Pr}$-O}`). However, it'd a good place to start!

Comment: Although I do not understand how this works, the expl3 code is significantly more readable than the traditional TeX code. Great.

Comment: **@Joseph** I was literally just coding to the tests shown :) I'm sure it can be improved. **@Aditya** some explanation to the code added at the bottom.

Comment: thanks for the example. Sorry I am late to tag this as the answer.